# shouldChangeCharactersIn not called on backspace with numpad

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
class TileSetupTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.delegate = self
    }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("pow")
        return true
    }
}
```

I expect that `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method will be called when any changes with text occurs but it isn't. It isn't called when I remove characters via backspace with numpad keyboard.

What's wrong?

Comment: @paulvs nope, In my case `shouldChangeCharactersIn` not called at all

Comment: @paulvs: Those question are about detecting BS inside that delegate method, but OP claims that the method is not called at all for the BS character, so I would not consider that a duplicate. – On the other hand, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you setting any other class as the delegate? A text field can only have one delegate.

Comment: @Alexandr: Is the delegate method called for other input?

Comment: If `shouldChangeCharactersIn` isn't being called at all, why is your question specifically about backspace?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, It's my mistake. `shouldChangeCharactersIn` isn't called when I trying to remove char with backspace, but it's called when I type something.

Comment: It won't be called if the text field is empty and you tap the backspace key. That's normal. Are you saying it isn't being called even if there is text in the text field and you tap backspace? It should be called in that case.

Comment: @rmaddy yep, it isn't called when there is a text in text field. I will try to reproduce it in empty project.

Comment: My project call it on deletion, just verified.

Comment: @rmaddy oh, it occurs with Google Keyboard, while default iOS keyboard works okay. Is it a bug?

Comment: it also occurs with numpad keyboard. Only default keyboard works as expected.

Comment: Had the same problem with custom keyboard

Comment: ever solve this? I'm seeing it with the built-in numpad. It is being called if I tap on the the text field again though, even though the text field already has focus. iOS 14.5.